# Postgres: Index on a status field with disproportionate distribution

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table with a large number of tasks, and some of the critical columns are,

```
    id: bigint autoincrement id
    customer_id: bigint
    created_time: Timestamp
    updated_time: Timestamp
    status: int (1: init, 2: inprogress, 3: success, 4: failed: 5: aborted)
    type: int (around 200+ possible values)
```

---

Due to the nature of the workload, the rough distribution is,

```
status=1: <1000
status=2: few thousands
status=3: 500 million
status=4: 5 million
status=5: 10 million
```

---

We have indexes on status, type, created_time, customer_id separately.

For some usecases, we want to monitor tasks that are not completed over a certain duration.

---

In this case, filtering to only for a status IN (1,2) are still slow. Would a partial index with (status,created,type) where status in (1,2) help?

A broader question is, when should we use a partial index?

Comment: a IN (1,) is a status = 1 OR status = 2 and would do a full table scan, you should always do a EXPLAIN ananlyse of your queires and check what the database makes of your code

Comment: Maybe.  Please show the query, and the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it being slow with the existing index.

Comment: Use `status <= 2` to encourage the engine to use the index (status). Please explain what do you mean by "over a certain duration". Even better, include the query in the question.